# How to use .indexOn for dynamic keys in firebase?

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a DB in Firebase with this structure:

```
{
  "chats" : {
    "-L-hPbTK51XFwjNPjz3X" : {
      "lastMessage" : "Hello!",
      "timestamp" : 1512590440336,
      "title" : "chat 1",
      "users" : {
        "Ol0XhKBksFcrYmF4MzS3vbODvT83" : true
      }
    }
  },
  "messages" : {
    "-L-hPbTK51XFwjNPjz3X" : {
      "-L-szWDIKX2SQl4YZFw9" : {
        "message" : "Hello!",
        "timestamp" : 1512784663447,
        "userId" : "Ol0XhKBksFcrYmF4MzS3vbODvT83"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "Ol0XhKBksFcrYmF4MzS3vbODvT83" : {
      "chats" : {
        "-L-hPbTK51XFwjNPjz3X" : true
      },
      "email" : "mm@gmail.com",
      "name" : "mm"
    }
  }
}
```

My code:

```
Database.database().reference().child("chats")
  .queryOrdered(‌​byChild: "users/(userId)").queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in .... }
```

When I try to get chat members or user chats, It shows this warnings:

- Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "chats/-L-hPbTK51XFwjNPjz3X" at /users to your security rules for better performance.
- Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "users/Ol0XhKBksFcrYmF4MzS3vbODvT83" at /chats to your security rules for better performance.

I found lots of solutions but anything works fine for me. I want to define  IndexOn rules in my DB, Can you help me?

Comment: What code triggers that warning?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This is the code:  Database.database().reference().child("chats").queryOrdered(byChild: "users/\(userId)").queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in   .... }

Comment: While it is possible to add an index for that user, it means you'd have to add more indexes as you add users to the app. This is unmaintainable. Instead consider adding an inverted index to your data structure: an additional list that contains the chats for a specific user. This type of duplication is quite common. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Ok! I try to do this by adding a list of chat ids in User data (it calls "chats", you can see). I need to put there all the chats information??

Comment: If you want to show the chats for a user, you start by loading `Database.database().reference("users").child(userId).child("chats")`. Then for each chat Id under that, you load the actual chat data from `/chats`. This is known as a client-side join.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I made your suggestion solution, but the message: "Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "chats/-L-hPbTK51XFwjNPjz3X" at /users to your security rules for better performance." still appear :(

Comment: That sounds like you're still querying across two levels with dynamic keys. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested